# React + openLayers 4 not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, openlayers

I am using PhpStorm to develop react app with openlayers support. I have used this wrapper for openlayers https://github.com/allenhwkim/react-openlayers everything works fine if I use default Layer.Tile which uses openstreetmap as source I think. But when I try to specify my custom XYZ tile source I am getting `a.V is not a function` in console. I have double checked that I am using same openlayers version (4.0.1) as wrapper. This only looks like som packaging error so I tried to delete `node_modules` and redownload all used modules but it is still not working.

PhpStorm uses `create-react-app` npm module to create app. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Hey horin did you find a solution for this?

Comment: let me know if get solution

Comment: React + OpenLayers 4 is working. Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/l731x5om9q